# Texture Maps Downloading Option Details

Tags: texturing, normal-map

When downloading a texture from any site there are plenty of maps option. Now how can I know which maps I need? In other words, What are the difference between each and every maps?
If there is any tutorial then plz suggest.
Thanks in advance !!
[image]

Comment: Maybe start here - https://www.cgbookcase.com/textures/how-to-use-pbr-textures-in-blender. However, this only describes a metal-roughness workflow, the other is specular-glossy, which appears to be what the maps you are downloading are for. They are just 2 slightly different ways of doing the same thing. You can read more in detail about it here - https://marmoset.co/posts/pbr-texture-conversion/. Oh, and for the most-part you don't need 16-bit maps.

Comment: Hello :). Your example is from poliigon.com. They have [an entire page](https://help.poliigon.com/en/collections/858726-blender) about using their materials in Blender. They also offer a converter addon, which does most of the work for you.